# Django model namespace error: missing field in ModelField form

Tags: python, django

I'm learning django (1.9.2) and have an namespace error in one of my forms that I can't understand when I `runserver` (also occurs when I `makemigrations`, just in case my database schema isn't current):

```
  File "/path/to/my_project/forms.py", line 11, in Meta
    product_code,
NameError: name 'product_code' is not defined
```

Here is the relevant code:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
import uuid

class Product(models.Model):
    product_code = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    #other fields, etc
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from my_project.models import Product

class InsertProduct(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Product
        fields = (
            product_code,
            #other fields, etc
        )
```

I'm importing the `Product` model, (and if I don't, I get an error so it's clearly required) but it doesn't seem to be recognising the Product namespace. If I comment out `product_code`, the interpreter simply complains that the next field is missing from `Product`. What must I do here to get my form to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Field names [should be strings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform), therefore you need to enclose them in quotes, such as:

```
fields = (
    'product_code',
    #other fields, etc
)
```

Comment: Oh wow, I feel really stupid now. Thanks for the quick answer.